# Status of procedures(methods and operations) in objects in Design Patterns

Tags: c++, oop, object, design-patterns

I am reading the book *Design Patterns* written by *Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson, John Vlissides*.

Page 11, it is written :
"An object packages both data and the `procedures` that operate on the data".

But I still have a question :

When you code in C++ : 
when an object is instantiated, does it really have in  its own Assembly code of the methods generated by the compiler  ? 
Or is the method common to all `objects` generated from the same class ?

That's a question that I have since a while.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do.you care? Is there any discernable difference between the two cases?

Comment: the part you quote is about the concept (that applies the same across many languages), while your question is about implementation details, thats quite different stories and it is not clear what your question really is about.

Comment: The method is common to all objects, it has an implicit parameter (`this`) which allows it to operate on any particular object. This is how all C++ implementations operate, but the language doesn't actually require this (AFAIK).

Comment: In add. to @john: If you ever wondered how `this` is initialized for every member function call... The (address of the) object for which a member function is called is usually passed like the other arguments internally. (I once found this out when I looked into ASM code when I stumbled over the same question like you.) ;-)

Comment: To explain better my question : suppose you have 2 objets a and b of class C in C++. And suppose C has a method f.  a and b encapsulate variables and methods as it is written. But Do a and b have their own code for the same function f. Or f is only defined one time in Assembly, and a and b call the same location when they call f ?

Comment: Re your last comment. Why do.you care? Is there any discernable difference between the two cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code associated with a class is constant -- there is no way in the language to change it, and it's the same for all instances of a class, so it is NOT copied anew for each instance.

Generally, all instances of the same class share the same code, but that doesn't mean a method execution always executes exactly the same instructions in memory:

- methods can be inlined, in which case the method implementation is copied into the calling function and optimized separately in that context;
- templated classes produce different machine code implementations of the methods for every unique set of template arguments;
- methods defined in headers can turn into machine code in many object modules.  Linkers will try to merge all the copies, but that's not really required and doesn't always happen universally.

Probably none of that matters to you right now.  The important distinction is that all the machine code method implementations are produced at *compile* time, and they are not copied or otherwise manipulated by the running program.

Comment: Your explanation helped me a lot to clarify my ideas between what happens at *compile time* and at *runtime*.